# Stretchable delimiters ignoring overline

Tags: delimiters

I would like adjustable delimiters to ignore overlines. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 $\left\{ f \right\} \; \left\{ \overline{f} \right\}$
\end{document}
```

The braces in the right case are noticeably larger than in the left case.
I would like adjustable delimiters to produce the same output in both cases.

Any idea how could I do this?

Comment: `\vphantom{f}\smash{\overline{f}}`

Comment: Just omit `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @egreg, while your suggestion addresses the use-case of the OP's MWE, there are many other use cases (fractions, square roots, exponents, etc) where the issue still comes into play.  I mention that for other readers, since I know that you know that already.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- but implicit in egreg's comment is that it's more often than not a bad idea to use `\left` and `\right`, but to select the appropriate size intentionally.  granted, doing this well comes only with experience, but too many authors *always* use `\left` and `\right` (and so do some "helpful" input software aids), and the resulting mess causes real problems in a publishing production environment.  this is a "best practices" situation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton No argument from me on that one.  And you are right that it is a trap that is fallen into easily by novice users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I introduce `\noverline{}`.  You probably want to use it only when needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\noverline[1]{\vphantom{#1}\smash{\overline{#1}}}
\begin{document}
 $\left\{ f \right\} \; \left\{ \noverline{f} \right\}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, and it works with accents / diacritics too :) Thanks!