# Overlines, delimiters, and overlines again

Tags: accents, delimiters

Follow-up question to: [Stretchable delimiters ignoring overline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313878/stretchable-delimiters-ignoring-overline)

Consider the following code:

```
$\left\{ f \right\} \; \left\{ \overline{f} \right\}$
```

The output in this case is not very satisfying, since braces in the right-hand example are extended to cover the overline, producing different brace height. In the mentioned question, a solution was proposed by @Steven B. Segletes:

```
\newcommand\noverline[1]{\vphantom{#1}\smash{\overline{#1}}}
$\left\{ f \right\} \; \left\{ \noverline{f} \right\}$
```

So far so good. Now I want to introduce an overline above the whole braced set, but the two overlines are typeset at the same height, so the outer one (which I would like to be slightly above) fully covers the inner one:

```
\newcommand\noverline[1]{\vphantom{#1}\smash{\overline{#1}}}
$\noverline{\left\{ f \right\} \; \left\{ \noverline{f} \right\}}$
```

Any clue how to obtain this? In the document I am currently typesetting I need to nest delimiters and overlines up to 3 levels, so I am afraid a one-shot solution will not cut it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In my application, it is.

Comment: I don't know a simple, general fix, but the particular situation can be addressed by introducing a `\vphantom` exponent, as in `$\noverline{\left\{ f \right\}^{\vphantom{x}} \; \left\{ \noverline{f} \right\}}$`.  Change the `x` to something else to affect the offset.

Comment: For something more general, a `stackengine` approach, such as `\myoverline` at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167954/overline-thickness/167995#167995 allows offsets to be specified, and may help you in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I show it 5 times.  1st example shows the `\left...\right` problem, example 2 shows the fix for that from [Stretchable delimiters ignoring overline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313878/stretchable-delimiters-ignoring-overline).

The current problem is shown in example 3, with a `\vphantom` fix given in example 4 and the `\myoverline` fix in example 5,as referenced in [Overline thickness](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167954/overline-thickness/167995#167995), and modified to take an optional real number for the overline offset.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\parskip 1ex \relax
\parindent 0pt\relax
\newcommand\noverline[1]{\vphantom{#1}\smash{\overline{#1}}}
\newcommand\myoverline[2][1.2]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#2$}%
  \stackengine{#1\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#2$}{\rule{\wd0}{.4\LMpt}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}%
}}
\begin{document}
Original, with problem:\\
$\left\{ f \right\} \; \left\{ \overline{f} \right\}$

Referenced \verb|\noverline|:\\
$\left\{ f \right\} \; \left\{ \noverline{f} \right\}$

problem in current question:\\
$\noverline{\left\{ f \right\} \; \left\{ \noverline{f} \right\}}$

Vphantom superscript:\\
$\noverline{\left\{ f \right\}^{\vphantom{x}} \; \left\{ \noverline{f} \right\}}$

With \verb|\myoverline| and \verb|\noverline|:\\
$\myoverline[1.9]{\left\{ f \right\} \; \left\{ \noverline{f} \right\}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The net result is that we can now dispense with `\overline` and replace the reference to it in `\noverline` with `\myoverline`, so that `\noverline` can now take the optional argument of `\myoverline` (and works across math styles).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\noverline[2][1.2]{\vphantom{#2}\smash{\myoverline[#1]{#2}}}
\newcommand\myoverline[2][1.2]{\ThisStyle{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle#2$}%
  \stackengine{#1\LMpt}{$\SavedStyle#2$}{\rule{\wd0}{.4\LMpt}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}%
}}
\begin{document}
$\noverline[1.9]{\left\{ f \right\} \; \left\{ \noverline{f} \right\}}$

$\scriptscriptstyle\noverline[1.9]{\left\{ f \right\} \; \left\{ \noverline{f} \right\}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: If one wants the smaller math style overline to remain as thick as in display style (which is the case for the original `\overline`), then one need merely change the `.4\LMpt` length to `.4pt`, in the definition of `\myoverline`.

Comment: This works awesome, and it gave me quite a lot of insight on how to do a few other things. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jaeya Glad to have been of some assistance.

Comment: I posted an answer below that automatically sets spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to this 5 years later with a (IMHO) better answer; feel free to comment.

```
\tl_const:Nn \wine_log@olshrink {0.6mu}
\tl_const:Nx \wine_log@olshrinkfw {\exp_not:N \tex_mkern:D \muskip_eval:n {\wine_log@olshrink}}
\tl_const:Nx \wine_log@olshrinkbw {\exp_not:N \tex_mkern:D \muskip_eval:n {-\wine_log@olshrink}}
\dim_new:N \wine_log@olht
\dim_new:N \wine_log@olprev
\dim_new:N \wine_log@olnat
\dim_new:N \wine_log@oltemp
\box_new:N \wine_log@olbox
\box_new:N \wine_log@phantom

\cs_new:Npn \wine_log_overline:nn #1 #2 {
    \ensuremath{
        \group_begin:
        \dim_set:Nn \wine_log@olprev {\wine_log@olht}
        \dim_zero:N \wine_log@olht
        \dim_gzero:N \wine_log@oltemp
        \hbox_set:Nn \wine_log@olbox {\ensuremath {#2}}
        \dim_set_eq:NN \wine_log@olht \wine_log@oltemp
        \dim_set:Nn \wine_log@olnat {\box_ht:N \wine_log@olbox}
        \box_set_ht:Nn \wine_log@olbox {
            \dim_max:nn {\wine_log@olht} {\box_ht:N \wine_log@olbox}
        }
        \hbox_set:Nn \wine_log@olbox {
            \ensuremath {\wine_log@shortened_overline:n {\box_use_drop:N \wine_log@olbox}}
        }
        \dim_gset:Nn \wine_log@oltemp {
            \dim_max:nn {\wine_log@olprev} {\box_ht:N \wine_log@olbox}
        }
        \bool_if:nF {#1} {
            \box_set_ht:Nn \wine_log@olbox {\wine_log@olnat}
        }
        \box_use_drop:N \wine_log@olbox
        \group_end:
    }
}

\cs_new:Npn \wine_log@shortened_overline:n #1 {
    \wine_log@olshrinkfw
    \tex_overline:D {\wine_log@olshrinkbw #1 \wine_log@olshrinkbw}
    \wine_log@olshrinkfw
}
```

Comment: Could you state it more specifically?